# Getting replies to a tweet by another person

Tags: twitter

What's the fastest way to get all the replies to a particular tweet from another person? (besides searching for his username, which is not effective if the tweet is not his latest)

Can this be done at all with the web interface? Or is it possible with any popular desktop client?

Comment: Okay so let me get this clear ... you are talking about "in reply to" and not mentions which some users tend to do to dissociate someone trying to link to the original thread

Comment: "in reply" to lets me navigate backwards from a tweet; I'd like to navigate forward (i.e. get all the tweets that are "in reply to" the one I'm looking at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that twitter.com has rolled out this feature lately, now you can view all the replies to someone else's tweets by a single click.

Comment: Indeed. This question was posted in the times of the old UI.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Tweeplies](http://tweeplies.qwe3.com/) in the past, but I just tried it and didn't get any results.  Not sure if it is a temporary issue or if it no longer works.

Comment: That's a lot closer to what I want. Unfortunately, it shows only links, but not the text of the tweets :-( I voted you up, I'll accept this answer if nothing better appears.

Answer (score 0):

Both TweetDeck and HootSuite have the option to view replies. In HootSuite if someone replies to a tweet you can click "view conversation" and in TweetDeck you can click "in reply to".

I had another look around and found this - http://twickie.pirillo.com/?rf=1 - where you can put in the ID of a tweet and it will bring back the replies. Tested it on one of my tweets and the results look good.

Comment: In TweetDeck, you click "in reply to" on the reply tweet to view the original tweet.  The OP wants to find all replies to the original tweet if I understood correctly.

Comment: @rchern your are correct. Neither TweetDeck nor HootSuite seem to provide that.

Comment: just tried twickie with this tweet: 18178961085. It didn't show any replies, when there are many, from several hours ago. Remember that I'm trying to see replies to _other people's tweets_